# Lost resources after importing project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I've been writing my java in a text-editor, compiling and running my code with a batch-file. I'd put all my resources (.png-files) in the bin-folder for my classes to read.

this is the structure of the map.

```
MyProject
  bin
  src
  batch-file
```

After 8 months of coding in Notepad, I finally decided to give an IDE a chance and went with Eclipse. I created a project called MyProject, having understood that was the way to import existing source code. Next thing I know, my .png files doesn't exist anywhere on my computer (I can't find them with Windows search function) I am very upset and angry and regret having deployed Eclipse at all. Can someone PLEASE give me good news and tell me how to get those lost resources back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No good news my friend...if you decided to do that big jump you should read something about how eclipse (or another ide) organizes projects....specifically the result of incremental compiler (classes) are written (by defaults) in a directory called... bin!.. probably that's the reason why you're not finding your files...you lost them
.

Comment: I'm just going in denial mode now.. Oh my god.. no. >.< I spend literally 300 hours producing those files. I can't believe it. I wanna go to court!... thank your for the answer

Comment: I'm not an expert about these topics but you should try with some recovery software

Comment: My God! Thank you, thank you, thank you! I recovered my files with a program called Recuva. I can't believe I was so ready to give up. THANK YOU! I wish I could upvote more than once.